# Fit a bezier curve to spatial lines objects in R

Tags: r, spatial, bezier, polyline

I'm trying to made a flow map in R, which so far I've managed to do, but due to my map only covering the space of one country gcIntermediate from the geosphere will create spatial lines for me, but they have no curve.

I thought maybe I could add a bezier curve to my lines, but I'm having zero luck with working out how I might do that.

```
long <- runif(10000, 49.92332, 55.02101) #Random co-ordinates 
lat <- runif(10000, -6.30217, 1.373248) # Random co-ordinates

df <- as.data.frame.matrix(data.frame(Lat.1 = sample(lat, 10), 
                 Long.1 = sample(long, 10),
                 Lat.2 = sample(lat, 10),
                 Long.2 = sample(long, 10))) # Dataframe of flow beginning to flow end

lines <- gcIntermediate(df[,c("Long.1", "Lat.1")], df[,c("Long.2", "Lat.2")], 500, addStartEnd = TRUE) #Create spatial lines with the geosphere package

plot(lines) #Some very straight lines
```

My problem comes when setting a start and end point for the bezier line, as the function in the `bezier` package only seems to accept one value for start and one for end, which given each point needs two values (long, lat) to define it I'm a bit stumped by.

I won't bore you with all of the different things I've tried with the bezier package (as none of them worked), here are some things that didn't work

```
bezier(sep(0,1,100), lines, lines$Long.1~lines$Lat.1, lines$Long.2~lines$Lat.2) # Won't accept a line object and I don't think Long.1 etc exist anymore

bezier(sep(0,1,100), df, df$Long.1~df$Lat.1, df$Long.2~df$Lat.2) #Hoped that if I used a formula syntax I could combine the long/lat of the starting and ending points respectively (I can't)
```

Has anyone got any insight on this? It's quite frustrating being so close and yet so far.